# How to get Color object in java from css-style string which describes color?

Tags: java, awt

For example, I have strings `#0f0`, `#00FF00`, `green` and in all cases I want to transform them to `Color.GREEN`.

Are there any standard ways or maybe some libraries have necessary functionality?

Comment: Do you want the actual constant, or would you settle for a `Color` whose RGB value was 0x00FF00?  Unless you know you will only ever have values that are `Color` constants, the latter may be more appropriate.

Comment: You're right, sure. I want any colors and Color.GREEN was just (not the best) example.

Answer (score 2):

First, I apologize if the below isn't helpful - that is, if you know how to do this already and were just looking for a library to do it for you.  I don't know of any libraries that do this, though they certainly may exist.

Of the 3 strings you gave as an example, `#00FF00` is the easiest to transform.

```
String colorAsString = "#00FF00";
int colorAsInt = Integer.parseInt(colorAsString.substring(1), 16);
Color color = new Color(colorAsInt);
```

If you have `#0f0`...

```
String colorAsString = "#0f0";
int colorAsInt = Integer.parseInt(colorAsString.substring(1), 16);
int R = colorAsInt >> 8;
int G = colorAsInt >> 4 & 0xF;
int B = colorAsInt & 0xF;
// my attempt to normalize the colors - repeat the hex digit to get 8 bits
Color color = new Color(R << 4 | R, G << 4 | G, B << 4 | B);
```

If you have the color word like `green`, then you'll want to check first that all CSS-recognized colors are within the Java constants.  If so, you can maybe use reflection to get the constant values from them (uppercase them first).

If not, you may need to create a map of CSS strings to colors yourself.  This is probably the cleanest method anyway.