# Calling the color type from a string

Tags: java, colors

Ok, so I'm sure this is really simple, but here goes nothing:

So say I'm calling the method master here, and color is one of the parameters:

```
master("RED");
```

Here is the master method:

```
public static void master(String color) {
   g.setColor(Color.color)
}
```

Disregard the g.SetColor, it's from a class that you probably don't have, the point is that when I call the string value of "RED" I intend on the color to be set to red. Otherwise I'd have to do it manually like this:

```
g.setColor(Color.RED);
```

I'm just confused why java isn't recognizing the color value when I call the color String.

Comment: Your method definition should accept the parameters that you want to pass and vice verse `public static void master(String color){}`

Comment: I edited the question. Accidentally posted before finishing.

Comment: There are 16,777,216 colors in the RGB range from 0-255.  Do you intend defining that many strings?  The basic fact is that the very limited number of color constants are not worth defining strings for, and more generally, it becomes unmanageable.

Comment: This question is related: (it boils down to the same answer as @ajb posted) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826894/how-to-get-color-object-in-java-from-css-style-string-which-describes-color

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Color.RED` is calling a constant value. You can't call `Color."RED"`

`RED` refers to a static field in the class `Color` and you can't call that with a String. It's the same as trying to call a variable in your code with a String. It doesn't work that way.

Instead, create this method:

```
public static void master(Color color) {
   g.setColor(color);
}
```

and call it like this:

```
master(Color.RED);
```

---

However, you could use [<kbd>Color.parseColor</kbd>](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#parseColor%28java.lang.String%29) instead if you would like to use a String parameter.

Perhaps:

```
public static void master(String color) {
   g.setColor(Color.parseColor(color));
}
```

and call it like this:

```
master("#FF0000");
```

Comment: Aha! Nice. I like the way this works. Simpler than the mapping answer. Thank you!

Comment: @Chief120 No problem. Check my update for another way to parse a colour (pick a preference).

Answer (score 3):

You have a parameter named `color`.  `Color.color` looks for a member named `color` in the `Color` class, and there isn't one (I think).  It has *nothing* to do with your `color` parameter.  The declarations like

```
static Color RED = <whatever>;
```

in the `Color` package define names that you can use in your program.  But those names are not stored in your program as strings that are available at runtime (except by reflection, but that may be too complicated).

You'll need a method that looks up the color-name string in some table, and converts it to a `Color`.  Since it looks like `getColor` doesn't work, you may need to build your own `Map<String,Color>` and initialize it like

```
m.put("RED", Color.RED);
m.put("BLUE", Color.BLUE);
...
```

This [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) explains more about `Map`s.

Comment: This is clever, but the other answer is a bit simpler. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A `Color` object and a String value representing that object are two completely different things.

If you want to get a `java.awt.Color` object from a String such as "Red", then you have to use some sort of method to convert it to the color it represents.

Try this:

```
Color realColor = (Color) Color.class.getField(color).get(null);
g.setColor(realColor);
```

This will first get the corresponding Color object for that String, then after it gets a `Color` object it will call the `setColor` method.

---

**Edit:** If all you require is just being able to specify the Color from another bit of code outside of that method (and it doesn't have to be a String), then you could always just pass it an actual Color object.

For example,

```
public static void master(Color color) {
    g.setColor(color);
}
```

and you would use this somewhere else as

```
master(Color.RED);
```

This makes the `master()` method pretty useless (unless you're going to include more logic in there), but it definitely beats having to parse a String color when you don't need to.

Comment: It won't - this method looks up a system property with the argument name and use its value as the color. Check the Javadoc of this method: `Finds a color in the system properties.`

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't quite work properly. All I intend on doing is being able to declare what color I want in a parameter so I don't have to rewrite the entire method with a different color.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice that. Updated answer to fix this for most of your normal colors.

Comment: Not sure I like the fix either, but that's just me

Comment: @Chief120, where exactly are you intending to get the Color from?

Comment: The alternative that @peter just posted should work, but you have to catch a bunch of reflection-related exceptions.

Comment: Yes, there is more logic, I just took everything else out to simplify the question. Thank you!